# Problems of creating a Dockerfile for .net core application

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, .net-core

I'm new to docker, so I would like to ask for help creating a Dockerfile for a .net core application.
The application has the following architecture:

```
   FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService
    │   ├───FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api
    │   ├───FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Logic
    │   └───Dockerfile
    │ 
    ├───FarmHouse.Services.Common
    │   └───FarmHouse.Services.Common.Models
    │   
    └───FarmHouse.Services.EmailService
        ├───FarmHouse.Services.EmailService.Api
        ├───FarmHouse.Services.EmailService.Logic
        └───Dockerfile
```

These three projects (`FarmHouse.Services.EmailService`, `FarmHouse.Services.Common` and `FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService`) are in the same solution and  `FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService` uses objects from the `Common` project, i.e. `FarmHouse.Services.Common` is a dependency for it.

I want other services to link to Common as well. My Dockerfile for AuthenticationService looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ./*.sln .
COPY ./FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Logic/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Logic.csproj ./FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Logic/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Logic.csproj
COPY ./FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api.csproj ./FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api.csproj
COPY ./FarmHouse.Services.Common/FarmHouse.Services.Common.Models/FarmHouse.Services.Common.Models.csproj ./FarmHouse.Services.Common.Models/FarmHouse.Services.Common.Models.csproj

RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY ./ ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api.dll"]
```

And when I run `docker build` from the parent folder, I see the following errors:

```
>docker build -t coreapp -f ./FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService/Dockerfile .

#14 1.643 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.406/NuGet.targets(282,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/app/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api.csproj" was not found. [/app/FarmHouseServices.sln]417050dbf1abf19fd7c8a7a0eb5d56150a                                                         0.0s
    #14 1.643 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.406/NuGet.targets(282,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/app/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Logic/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Logic.csproj" was not found. [/app/FarmHouseServices.sln]                                                                                       0.0s
    #14 1.643 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.406/NuGet.targets(282,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/app/FarmHouse.Services.Common/FarmHouse.Services.Common.Models/FarmHouse.Services.Common.Models.csproj" was not found. [/app/FarmHouseServices.sln]uthenticationService/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api.csproj ./FarmHous  0.0s
    #14 1.643 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.406/NuGet.targets(282,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/app/FarmHouse.Services.EmailService/FarmHouse.Services.EmailService.Api/FarmHouse.Services.EmailService.Api.csproj" was not found. [/app/FarmHouseServices.sln]                                                                                                                      1.0s
    #14 1.643 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.406/NuGet.targets(282,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/app/FarmHouse.Services.EmailService/FarmHouse.Services.EmailService.Logic/FarmHouse.Services.EmailService.Logic.csproj" was not found. [/app/FarmHouseServices.sln]
```

Please, advice how to modify a Dockerfile in this case or the architecture.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting those errors because you're running `dotnet` commands at `.sln` file level, and therefore `dotnet` tries to restore all the `.csproj` files in the solution, which haven't been copied.

Try replacing your `dotnet restore` and `publish` commands with:

```
RUN dotnet restore ./FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api.csproj

RUN dotnet publish ./FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api.csproj -c Release -o out
```

You can alternatively copy all `.csproj` files and let them be restored with simply `dotnet restore`, but I would use the project path for the `dotnet publish` command anyway.

Comment: When I try to do this, I get the following warning:
`#17 4.032 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.406/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2084,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "FarmHouse.Services.Common.Models". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/app/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api/FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api.csproj].`And then an error stating that the type from the Common project was not found.

Comment: You need to replicate whatever folder structure appears in the projects that are referenced in `FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService.Api.csproj` when copying them, or those relative paths won't work.
You seem to be missing the `FarmHouse.Services.Common` part when copying the common project.

Comment: Back to the question, since I decided to create pipelines in gitlab. Locally, docker build works well, but gitlab does not:
`before_script:
- apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community nodejs-npm
- npm i -g heroku
- docker login -u _ -p token registry.heroku.com
    script:
        - cd FarmHouseServices
        - docker build -f ./FarmHouse.Services.AuthenticationService/Dockerfile .`

Comment: Feel free to create a separated question, it will very difficult to understand the new problem just using comments.